# mysql REGEXP to match a string ending in 2 digits that are preceded only by non-digits

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select

I have struggled quite a bit with this.

In MySQL I would like to query a column for strings that end with a double-digit number. I don't care what else comes before, as long as the last characters are **two digits preceded by at least one non-digit**

For instance, these strings should match:

```
"Nov. 12th, 60"

"34 Bar 56"

"Foo-BAR-01"

"33-44-55"

"-------88"

"99"
```

When I do this:

```
SELECT <string> REGEXP <pattern>
```

Now, the `<pattern>` bit is what I need help on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "^.*[^0-9][0-9]{2}$";
```

Regex Explanation:

```
^.*[^0-9][0-9]{2}$

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives «*»
Match any single character that is NOT present in the list below and that is NOT a line break character «[^0-9]»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Assert position at the very end of the string «$»
```

Comment: Thank you, Pedro. I appreciate your giving so much time to my question.

Comment: Well, following your edits, please note that this one: `"^.*[[:<:]][^0-9]?[0-9]{2}[[:>:]]$"` is broken! Yeah, your initial answer did not match my `99`, but I was willing to overlook, since that particular string was an edge case, and unlikely to occur in my data.

Comment: Nevertheless, in the academic spirit, do see how to bring in the case for the `99`. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to describe all the string, the end should suffice:

```
SELECT 'Nov. 12th, 60' REGEXP '(^|[^[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]{2}$';
SELECT '99' REGEXP '(^|[^[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]{2}$'
```

So in short the two digits at the end `[[:digit:]]{2}$` are preceded by a non digit character `[^[:digit:]]`, OR `|` the begining of the string `^`.

Note: you can write it in a less posix style, it doesn't change anything (only a little shorter):

```
SELECT 'Nov. 12th, 60' REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{2}$';
```

Comment: Thank you @Casmir. Your patterns did work for my situation. But let me officially accept the first answer that came in. By the way, those POSIX styles, though more verbose, might actually be more 'memorable'.